# Is there any way to go back from `std::function` to a pointer?

Tags: c++, function, types

Imagine the following scenario:

```
typedef std::function<float(float)> A;
typedef float(*B)(float);

A foo();
void bar(B b);
```

You wish to do something along the lines of:

```
bar(foo());
```

Obviously this does not work. Mainly because `A` can contain a state and `B` is a function pointer. What if we know that `A` does not contain a state and we wish to somehow take it's "meaning" and put it into something that can be passed for a `B`?

Is it impossible?

Comment: Do you know the *exact* type contained?  A std function with a given signature can contain many stateless types.  If so, maybe.  Of not, no.  As an aside, if you know what the std function contains, why not just pass *that* type instead?

Comment: It seems `std::function::target` can return a pointer to the type, but only if you know what the type is. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target

Comment: `foo()` is `float`, not function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can ensure that the callable object stored in A is a function pointer or a lambda with an empty capture list, you can simply get a function pointer in this way:

```
foo().target<B>();
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, a `std::function` can "box" some [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (e.g. the value of some [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)). And a closure contains *both* code and data (the closed values). So I believe that you cannot *portably* convert it to a naked function pointer. BTW, because conceptually closures are mixing code and data languages not providing them (like C) practically requires [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) (i.e. the convention to pass every function pointer with some additional data, look into GTK for a concrete example).

Some implementation specific tricks might make a [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29) function on the stack (e.g. dynamically generate, perhaps with [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), some machine code containing a *pointer* to the closure, etc.).  But this is not portable and system specific (in particular because the stack needs to be executable)

Answer (score 0):

> What if we know that A does not contain a state and we wish to somehow take it's "meaning" and put it into something that can be passed for a B?

Even that isn't sufficient. `std::function` provides a [`target()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) member function, that if you know the exact type of the underlying functor, you can get it back. So we can do, for instance:

```
void print(int i) { std::cout << i; }

std::function<void(int)> f = print;
auto ptr = f.target<void(*)(int)>();  // not null
(*ptr)(42);                           // works
```

However, even if our functor `f` doesn't contain state, that doesn't mean that its underlying type is precisely `void(*)(int)`. It could be a completely different function pointer, in which case we wouldn't be able to pull it out:

```
int square(int i) { return i*i; }

f = square;
ptr = f.target<void(*)(int)>(); // nullptr!
```

Or it could be a lambda, in which case we wouldn't even be able to *name* the type, much less pull it out:

```
f = [](int i){ std::cout << i; }; // same as print, right?
ptr = f.target<void(*)(int)>();   // ... nope :'(
```

---

Basically, type erasure is really type **erasure**. If you need the original underlying type, that's likely indicative of a bad design.